# PIvot and Formula function to show unique plus multiple results

Tags: excel, google-sheets, pivot-table, formula, google-sheets-formula

I've been racking my brain how to accomplish this but what I am trying to do is use a a pivot table to identify how many IDs only have the 1 skill and by which site.

I also want to show if they have more than one skill. For example they have Maths and Writing, by site.

I am also trying to do this via a formula.

Might sound a bit silly and i'm sorry but was hoping someone may be able to help.

I have shared my Google sheet showing this (i'm assuming I can do the same in excel).

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1btkhhYyVG_GYrz_SYXwO4wUsxq3ay3eZv5AOF7h95o4/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

As per the sample data provided, it seems that the ID's have just one site, so showing the order ID\Site\Skills, therefore I would suggest the PivotTable layout below, adding a subtotal to count the quantity of skills per ID, remove the `Grand Totals` as they are not required.

[image]

You may also want to sort the Data by the Skills count in ascendant order to show first the ID's with just one skill.

[image]

So this is your PivotTable:

[image]

Another Layout:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in excel. Either you make a PivotTable and make something like this.
[image: PivotTable Excel]

or you can just copy the ID, site and insert the skills like I have done in this picture.
Then use these formulas in the field. In the first column No Skills (Number of skills) I use the following formula: COUNTIF(A:A;F2)  Where A:A are the first column ("ID") in your original table and then in the rest cells I use the following formula COUNTIFS($A:$A;F2;$B:$B;I$1) where A:A are the same as above and B:B is the second column "Skills" in your original table and I1 is the Skills in the new table..

[image: New table]

Answer (score 0):

Is this the result you want?
[image]

If so, it was just a matter of moving "Site" above "skill" under the Column section of the Pivot Table Editor.  See below:
[image]